# Facing error in Angular project due to Ngrx version

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I deleted the node_modules and re-installed it.But still I am facing errors. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Checked the updated versions.
My Node version is 8.12.0
my NPM version is 6.4.1

Below is the error which I am facing

```
ERROR in node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/store.d.ts(30,31): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Extract'.
node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/store_module.d.ts(23,154): error TS2315: Type 'ModuleWithProviders' is not generic.
node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/store_module.d.ts(24,178): error TS2315: Type 'ModuleWithProviders' is not generic.
node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/store_module.d.ts(25,171): error TS2315: Type 'ModuleWithProviders' is not generic.
```

`Below is package.json file`

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^7.0.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^7.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.0",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.6.0",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This error is mentioned here: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/1488

It states that `Extract is introduced in Typescript 2.8. Which explains the errors.`

The above defined project is using TypeScript 2.7.2.

Consider upgrading your version of TypeScript.

(I also replied here: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-ngrx-getting-started/discussion)

Comment: oh wow thanks, I am doing your tutorial on pluralsight lol. Was working on user reducers and got this error

Comment: I am further getting error .....................
ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=2.7.2 and <2.8.0 but 2.8.4 was found instead.........................................................
I dont know why its taking as 2.8.4 indeed I put as 2.8.0

Comment: What version of Angular did it install? I thought Angular 6.1 supported Typescript 2.8.x.

Comment: Its working now, it was showing lot of errors, I deleted everything and make it same like it was previously and now its working even with 2.7.2 verison. I dont know the reason though

Comment: The same course lead me here, @DeborahK Your course is great, I'll try submitting a PR if I ever fixed this compatibility issues.

Comment: Someone already did and I just merged it this morning. THANKS!